# Dynamically link cell content in Mathematica?

Tags: front-end, dynamic

Is it possible to dynamically link the content of two cells? For example, can I set up a Notebook with two text cells that display the same value, and if the user types in one the other updates, etc.? I am familiar with Mathematica's dynamic functionality and at least the key concepts of the FrontEnd, and it seems like I should be able to assign a dynamic symbol to certain parts of a cell and just use that in an expression elsewhere, but I can't figure out how to programmatically access a cell's current content. The best I have been able to do is get a CellObject using `Cells[]`, e.g. where the first cell is a text cell containing "This is a test!", `Cells[][[1]]` gives

```
Cell[BoxData[
TemplateBox[{6849,"6849","\"Text\""},
"CellObject"]], "Output",
CellChangeTimes->{{3.5653627710636687`*^9, 3.5653627797706504`*^9}, {
3.5653628101959224`*^9, 3.5653628192779245`*^9}, 3.5653630492614017`*^9}]
```

but this doesn't include the cell's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this does it for you.  There are still some issues (see below).

```
nbA = CreateDocument[{Cell["Notebook A", "Title"],
    ExpressionCell[
     Dynamic[Refresh[
       NotebookWrite[dynamicCellObjB, NotebookRead[dynamicCellObjA]]; 
       dynamicCellObjB = First@Cells[nbB, CellTags -> "DynamicCell"]; 
       "cell to be updated:", TrackedSymbols -> {}, 
       UpdateInterval -> 5]]], 
    Cell["Edit this", "Text", CellTags -> {"DynamicCell"}]}];
dynamicCellObjA = First@Cells[nbA, CellTags -> "DynamicCell"];
nbB = CreateDocument[{Cell["Notebook B", "Title"], 
    Cell["Not this", "Text", CellTags -> {"DynamicCell"}]}];
dynamicCellObjB = First@Cells[nbB, CellTags -> "DynamicCell"];
```

You need something to trigger the update.  Notebooks live in the front end and `NotebookObjects`, while living in the kernel, are just references to the front end object.  Dynamic interactivity requires some variable change or event in the kernel to trigger an update.  Here I used `Dynamic[Refresh[.., UpdateInterval->5]]` to cause an update every five seconds.  You can change the update interval as you please.  Another key is that the connected cells are identified by a unique cell tag (`"DynamicCell"` was my choice of name).  There are some timing issues.  I occasionally got a message on start-up, if a symbol was evaluated before it was defined.

If it seems on the right track, I hope you can adapt it to your notebooks.

Comment: Thanks! This gets me on the right track.