# Repeating the contents of one cell in another, in "real time"

Tags: front-end

How could I create two Input cells, such that when the first is evaluated, the contents of the first are copied to the second? So for example, there would be two empty cells - let's call them A and B - and when the user enters `f[x_]:=x^2+4` in A, nothing happens.  When that same user evaluates cell A, then the contents of cell B are updated to be  `f[x_]:=x^2+4`.  There is a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16973/dynamically-link-cell-content-in-mathematica), but I don't need to be that low-level about things, and I also don't want automatic refreshing; only when cell A has been evaluated.

Comment: This may be useful for this: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellEvaluationFunction.html

Comment: @Szabolcs: Ok, thanks, this could be a very good place to start.  DO you know how I would use such a function to update the contents of another cell? It can't be just the usual Dynamic, because I need cell B to be an input cell.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to figure it out, but this is what I'd try (not sure it's the best or even that it would work):  first identify cell B somehow, e.g. with a cell tag.  Then make the CellEvaluationFunction locate cell B (NotebookLocate), select it, and replace its contents e.g. using NotebookWrite (NotebookApply? not sure).  Hope this helps.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Your suggestion definitely helped, and it works when I enter it directly into the notebook.  However, if I use it as an argument to CellEvaluationFunction, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use CellEpilog? :

```
CellPrint /@
  {ExpressionCell[ , "Input",
    CellTags -> "CellA",
    Background -> LightGray,
    CellEpilog :> Module[{contA},

      contA = NotebookRead[Cells[CellTags -> "CellA"]] /.
        {Cell[b_, "Input", ___], ___} :> b;
      NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "CellB", Next, CellTags];
      SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, CellContents];
      NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], contA]
      ]],
   ExpressionCell[, "Input", CellTags -> "CellB",
    Background -> LightOrange]
   };
```